# Stranded wire gauge too small for push-in connector(USA)

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, connectors

I'd like to use these push-in connectors along with the stranded wire connections inside a light fixture.

[3-port push-in connector](https://www.idealindustries.ca/products/in-surer-push-in-wire-connector-model-33-3-port-orange.html)

I'm using these connectors because space is limited inside the fixture. Two romex bundles come into the fixture. For each connection to the light, I need to connect two solid wires (from the romex cables) to the corresponding stranded wire inside the fixture.

The problem is the fixture's stranded wires are too small to work with the push-in connector. Is there a proper way to easily upsize stranded wire (like some kind of soldered terminal) such that it will work with the connector? (as opposed to splicing the stranded wire to a short solid jumper with a small wire nut).

Comment: What size are the fixture's stranded wires?

Comment: Yeah, what make and model is this fixture, and where'd you find it?

Answer (score 5):

### This cannot be a problem

The connectors are listed for a wide range of solid and stranded wire.  A wider range, in fact, than you are allowed to use inside fixtures, which must be no smaller than #18 for mains voltage - that's according to UL.

Now, if the fixture is not UL listed (or other NRTL), don't use it.  Especially if it's one of those foreign jobs obtained off Alibaba, AliExpress, eBay or Amazon.  Those are predominantly dangerous junk, and obviously they have not the slightest regard for our safety codes.  CE and CCC are not proper testing labs such as UL.

If it is a fixture of your own construction, that is between you and the AHJ, but you will at least need to retrofit the internal 120/240V wires to #18 or larger.

Comment: the 18 gauge stranded wire does  not have the requisite mechanical strength to be pushed into the connector